# I am not able to understand why output is coming 10 in this for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, cstdio

can anybody clear my doubt .. why this program is giving 10 as output.
can you please explain the mechanism .. for loop is also having ; before the statements also

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i ;
    for ( i =0 ; i<10 ; i++);
    {
      cout<<i ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: Well, it's `i`'s value after the `for()` loop was stopping due to this condition. What do you actually expect?

Comment: You have `;` after for loop.

Comment: yes ; is there . its not the syntax but what about the code here ..i mean 10  output

Answer (score 6):

```
for ( i =0 ; i<10 ; i++);
```

This is a *complete* loop, the semicolon at the end indicates an empty body. Hence it simply increments `i` eventually to `10`. The reason it's `10` (rather than `9`) is because that is when the continuation condition `i < 10` becomes false.

Which means that this little snippet:

```
{
    cout<<i ;
}
```

is a *once-executed* statement outputting the contents of `i` (left at `10` by the loop).

The braces in this case simply put the statement into an enclosed scope, they are not related to the loop at all.

So, if you want to output `i` each time through the loop, simply get rid of the semicolon so that the braces and their contents become the body of that loop.

Comment: but i max is 9 .. why it is printing the number of i 's ..

Comment: @bhabajitkashyap the loops ends once `i` equals 10, not 9.

Comment: @bhabajitkashyap, the loop exits when the continuation condition `i < 10` becomes false, and *before* executing the body of the loop for that potential iteration. That happens when `i` is ten. So, after loop exit, `i` will be set to `10`. I'll add that to the answer for completeness.

Comment: got the point . thnx for the support :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
for ( i =0 ; i<10 ; i++); // This means loop till i = 10 at which point loop breaks. This is because of ending the for loop with ';'
{ // start of scope
    cout<<i ; // Print the value of i which is 10 now
} // end of scope
```

Consider that the loop has reached a point where i = 9, so, 'i < 10' condition is true. 
Therefore, for the next iteration 'i++' will increment it to 10. 
Now again the test 'i < 10' is checked. At this point '10 < 10' test returns false and the for loop breaks and the value of i is 10.

Comment: but i max is 9 here..how it is printing 10

Comment: @bhabajitkashyap You need to understand how for loop works :). Consider i = 9, so, i < 10 condition is true. Therefore, for the next iteration 'i++' will increment it to 10. Now again the test 'i < 10' is checked. At this point '10 < 10' test returns false and the for loop breaks and the value of i is 10.

Comment: got the point ..thanks :-)